# FxCop warnings are thrown as errors by MSBuild. How do you change the errors back to warnings?

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I have a huge C# project/solution with 30+ .csproj files/modules. When I try to do MSBuild FxCop warnings are thrown as errors. How do I disable warnings as error setting by modifying .sln file or as a MSBuild flag.

FYI: I'm Trying to import FxCop rules into SonarQube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to disable this via a compiler flag `/p:CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors=false` passed to MSBuild

Final command that parallel rebuilds ResolverService with FxCop errors processed as warnings:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:Rebuild ResolverService.sln /m  /p:CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors=false`

This solution is preferable than going to each and every .csproj file and editing the `<CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>` tag to false.